# Error starting my business network within IBM Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am creating a business network with IBM Blockchain.
As I try to deploy the business within its directory, it fails with the message :

> Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network.
>   Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error:
>   Error: 2 UNKNOWN: transaction returned with failure:
>   ReferenceError: require is not defined Command failed".

The command I am using is this one

```
composer network start -c adminCard -n tutorial-network -V 0.0.1 -A admin -C credentials/admin-pub.pem -f delete_me.card
```

What should I do to fix this?